# How to copy row in one table to another only when that row doesn't exist in target table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join, sql-insert

I'm trying to write a statement that adds rows to the employee table for every entry in the contacts table that is not in the Employee table.

I also need to update the new entries in the Employees table with a new ManagerId that is = 3.

This is what I have so far, I think I have the syntax wrong for part of this.

```
INSERT INTO Employees
SELECT * FROM Contacts
Left Join Employees on Employees.Firstname = Contacts.FirstName 
and Employees.LastName = Contacts.LastName
WHERE Employees.FirstName and Employees.LastName = NULL
--set all new added employess's manager ID to 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following `insert` uses `not exists` to determine whether to insert a new row or not.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Employees (**List columns here**, ManagerId)
SELECT (**List columns here**, 3)
FROM dbo.Contacts C
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.Employees E
    WHERE E.FirstName = C.FirstName 
    AND E.LastName = C.LastName 
)
```

Points to note:

1. Always list all columns for `insert` and `select` - you will save yourself much future pain this way.
2. Its best practice to schema quality your objects.
3. Its best practice to alias your tables as it makes for more readable SQL.

Answer (score 1):

1. To insert new row into the one table from another table, you
   have to mention the column names because both table have different
   naming conventions and a different number of columns.
2. To map the column you must define the source and destination columns,
   both by their names and there positions in the table.

```
INSERT INTO Employees (Firstname, LastName, ManagerId, 'AND ALL OTHER COLUMNS WHICH YOU WANT TO COPY')
SELECT Firstname, LastName, 3, 'AND ALL OTHER COLUMNS WHICH YOU WANT TO COPY' FROM Contacts contacts
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
 SELECT 1
 FROM Employees e
 WHERE e.FirstName = contacts.FirstName 
 AND e.LastName = contacts.LastName 
)
```

Try this, and add your specific columns here `'AND ALL OTHER COLUMNS WHICH YOU WANT TO COPY'`